# Power BI How to Sum Matched 2 Columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables. First one represents sales values of company by department, product ID and month. Second table contains sales target by department and month. I want to add a column to second table. It should shows sum of values from table 1 with grouping department and month.

For Example: 
For 310101 in Februray sum of values is 110. So, the first row of table 2 should be 110.

Can you please help me with this DAX function?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculated column in both tables which will represent an unique ID (Eg: ID = Table1[Dpt ID] & Table1[Month]) and join the both tables by this ID field to create a relationship between these 2 tables.

[image]

Now, select all the columns from Table 2 and also select Value column from Table 1. You should get the sum by department.

[image]

Comment: Good solution @S.Jo but I'm wondering.. How can I set a slicer for filtering both two tables based on dep. ID and month? (Month and dep. ID can be select multiply)

Comment: Since both the tables are now related, you can use dep. ID and month as slicer from either of the 2 tables.
If this answers your question, mark it as accepted.